# Configure ESLint to throw error if hooks have no dependency array but array would require dependencies if put in

Tags: javascript, eslint

Is there a way to configure ESLint to throw an error or warning if a hook, like a `useEffect`, doesn't have a dependency array, but if a dependency array is put in, that array would require deps?

For example, the below `useEffect` doesn't throw an error or warning without a dependency array, but if I put one in, it throws a warning that it requires `setIsQSDashboardEnabled` as a dependency.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setIsQSDashboardEnabled(true);
    return () => {
      setIsQSDashboardEnabled(false);
    };
  });
```

Comment: You could maybe use [`no-restricted-syntax`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-syntax) with a selector like `CallExpression[callee.name=useEffect][arguments.length<2]` to detect hook calls without dependency arrays, but it would be much more complex (and require an entirely custom rule) to determine whether it _should_ have any dependencies.

Comment: I think this might actually be good enough for what we're looking for. Thanks!